# BrowserStack, Sauce Labs - same test, different results

Tags: cross-browser, saucelabs, browserstack

I've been cross-browser testing with Sauce for a while now. I recently heard about BrowserStack and decided to give it a try. I dig it... it's way faster, and the UI far more intuitive and cooperative.

It's taken me forever to find a way to get IE8 to recognize media queries. Respond.js didn't work no matter what I did (I tried everything under the sun), but eventually I tried css3-mediaqueries.js and it seemed to work right out of the chute.

But when I tested the same page in BrowserStack, thud, no media queries.

Can anyone tell me how it might be that the same test parameters (IE8, Windows 7, 1024x768) shows media queries working in Sauce, but not in BrowserStack?

Here is the stripped down test page link I was using:

http://www.ilium.com/test

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We (BrowserStack) are not sure why you are facing issue with respond.js. We tried [sample test page](http://users.telenet.be/willydesmadryl/Portfolio/js/scottjehl-Respond-b21c578/test/test.html), which works as expected. [image: Reference Image]

Your url, our test with IE8 VMware VM's and BrowserStack IE8 report the same result.
[image: local IE8 Image] 
Local IE8 VM
[image: BrowserStack IE8]
BrowserStack IE8

We went ahead to try to make it work like chrome. Enabling setting "Access data sources across domains" makes it work something like below, not exactly like other browsers like chrome.

[image: Enable Settings]
[image: New Look of ilium.com]

Let us know for any further clarifications.

Comment: Thanks @Nakul, you have a lovely application. So it appears then that Sauce's VMs must have the "Access data sources across domains" enabled, which from what I can see is not the default setting. But this actually deepens the mystery for me, as every single data source on my test page is cross domain and absolute linked. Shouldn't that mean no linked scripts and CSS would be working at all? Why does only the call to css3-mediaqueries.js (contained in an IE conditional comment) seem to be affected, I wonder?

Comment: To clarify, the jquery calls (scripts and css) go to code.jquery.com, and all others to the subdomain on which I've been building the actual site.

Comment: Sure enough, I was able to access the security settings on Sauce's VM, and "Access data sources across domains" is indeed enabled there. Disabling has the effect of ignoring media queries, though images on that domain still load. This happens even when I am on the same domain that css3-mediaqueries.js is hosted on. Baffling, though perhaps only so for this <10-SO-rep guy.

Comment: @MattKristiansen you are right, the documentation of the above setting, shouldn't cause such an issue but we are not entirely sure either, why you are facing such an issue because of it. :(

Comment: I marked this as the answer, though it looks like said answer raises a whole new question, which I'll post separately. Thanks for the help!